# Consulta MYSQL, Como obtener el TOP 10 de productos reflejando el 100 % de los registros?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

espero que puedan ayudarme, requiero sacar el **TOP 10** de una tabla de productos en **MySQL**, la estructura de la tabla es:

PRODUCTOS

1. id_producto.
2. nombre
3. precio
4. id_tipo

es una tabla con miles de registros pero quiero obtener los 10 primeros, pero sin perder los demás agrupándolos en otro registro llamado otros

`SELECT nombre, precio FROM productos WHERE id_tipo=12 ORDER BY precio DESC`
esta consulta me trae 100 registros, donde solo me interesa los 10 productos mas caros, y los 90 restantes requiero agruparlos en otro registro llamado otros(como en la imagen)[image: tabla de registros esperados]

Hasta ahora esto es lo que he intentado

```
SET @i:=0;
SET @suma:=0;
SELECT 
id_producto,
nombre,
precio,
total,
indice
FROM
(SELECT 
    id_producto,
    nombre,
        precio,
        IF(@i <= 10, SUM(precio), 0) AS total,
        @i:=@i + 1 AS indice
FROM
    productos
WHERE
    id_tipo = 12
GROUP BY id_producto
ORDER BY precio DESC limit 10) AS info
union all select 
"OTROS" as total,
nombre,
precio
GROUP BY id_producto
 ORDER BY precio desc
```

espero que me puedan ayudar, GRACIAS!
nota:
estoy utilizando mysql 5.6

Comment: Pon lo que tienes hecho para poderte ayudar

Comment: he actualizado, y agregado lo que llevo al momento

Comment: Ya arreglé, revisa

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT nombre, precio 
 FROM productos 
 WHERE id_tipo = 12 ORDER BY precio DESC limit 10)
Union
(SELECT "Otros", Sum(precio) precio
 FROM productos 
 WHERE id_tipo = 12 and no not in(select no from productos
   where id_tipo = 12
   order by precio desc limit 10)
)
```

Atendiendo al ejemplo que das te propongo la siguiente consulta:

Primero haces la consulta que te va a devolver los **10** primeros registros, para esto se usa la **cláusula limit**, que se encarga de devolver la cantidad de registros que deseas, en este caso es **10**.

Después vendría la segunda consulta la cual va a sumar el precio de todos los productos. Estas dos consultas se unen a través del **operador de conjunto union**, para que esté operador funcione ambos **select** deben devolver la misma cantidad de columnas y del mismo tipo, si la primera columna del primer **select** es **varchar**, pues su equivalente en la consulta **2** también debe ser **varchar**.

Como bien dices ese **"otros"** debe ser la suma total - la suma total de los **10** registros seleccionados de la primera consulta, una forma de hacer esto es en la segunda consulta, poner una subconsulta que descarte los productos seleccionados en la primera, para hacer esto se pregunta si el **campo "no"** no está en la subconsulta realizada.

Comment: viéndolo de la manera que lo explicas, en la segunda consulta que haces el union, se estarían sumando todos precios de los productos no?, necesitaría ese resultado menos los precios del top 10.

Comment: Dame un time, enseguida lo arreglo, pero obviando esto, te sirvio?

Comment: Ya arregle, mira a ver

Comment: al parecer tampoco me admite realizar la consulta por la versión me manda mensaje de error (MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery)

Comment: @DonaldoManzano y pq no cambias a una versión más nueva, estas pasando trabajo por gusto, tomate un tiempo e instala una nueva versión, te ahorrarás tiempo y esfuerzo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
   t1.*
FROM
(
   SELECT
      id_producto,
    nombre,
        precio,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER (
        ORDER BY precio DESC
    ) orden_por_precio
   FROM 
      productos
   WHERE
      id_tipo = 12
) t1
```

La sentencia anterior en columna `orden_por_precio` tendrá un valor de 1 en adelante.
Como observo resaltas en rojo en tu imagen es cuestión:

```
SELECT 
   t1.*
FROM
(
   /* El Query anterior */
) t1
WHERE t1.orden_por_precio<=10
```

Comment: trate de hacer esta consulta, pero me percate que la versión de mysql (5.6) no tiene esta funcionalidad de   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (..)